# Issue getting Collections.shuffle() for an array of doubles working

Tags: java, jsp, collections, javabeans, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle an array of doubles in a java bean for use in a JSP file.

In the default constructor of my java bean I have:

```
amounts  = new double[] {0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5. 3, 3.5, 4};

Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(amounts));
```

I can call the methods of the bean fine but for some reason the amounts array stays the same, so it is either not shuffling or the default constructor is not executing. No errors are thrown so I believe it may be the constructor not executing but I cannot figure out why.

In my JSP I use:

```
<jsp:useBean id="myBean" class="logic.logicBean" scope = "session" />
```

I thought in doing that, the default constructor would execute, is this wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `double[]` instead of `List<Double>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(amounts)` expects `T...`, where `T` is an object type. The problem here is that you're passing `double[]`, so your list is actually `List<double[]>` - not `List<Double>`. The other answers are incorrect, because `Arrays.asList` is guaranteed to "write-through" to the backing array.

See [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))...

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)

To prove it, try declaring `amounts` as instead `Double[]` and allowing the compiler to autobox (also make sure to correct the types of the literals, i.e. either add `.0` or `D` suffix):

```
amounts = new Double[] { 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4.0 };
```

Notice that it will now function correctly :-)

Comment: Cool. I tried and it worked. How does it change the original? Through a pointer? Thread? I dont think its a thread.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık `Arrays.asList` uses an implementation that is required to just implement `List` and `RandomAccess` and use the underlying array. [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) only ever *swaps* elements ("This implementation traverses the list backwards ... **swapping a randomly selected element into the "current position"**"), which doesn't require the operations `Arrays.asList` does not support (i.e. insertion and removal).

Comment: Awesome!! I don't understand what the difference is between Double and double though, care to explain? Thanks for finding my error!!

Comment: @cheeseman `Double` is an object type, specifically the [wrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) for `double` that the compiler automatically handles [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for. `double` as you know is a primitive data type, while `double[]` and all array types are object types; passing `double[]` to `Arrays.asList` requires `T...` parameter for `T` being some object type, and since you passed a single *object*, it thinks you want `List<double[]>`.

Comment: @cheeseman by explicitly making `amounts` of type `Double[]`, then the compiler recognizes you passed an array of `Double` objects (`T...` matches `Double[]` for `T` being `Double`) and thus creates `List<Double>`, which can actually be meaningfully shuffled (in the way you expected it to be). Shuffling a list of a single object, on the other hand, doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: I think I understand, some very interesting stuff, I shall read more in to it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @cheeseman there's plenty of good stuff written in the Java Tutorials I linked to in my earlier comment :-)